# PySpark isin function

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am converting my legacy Python code to Spark using PySpark.

I would like to get a PySpark equivalent of:

```
usersofinterest = actdataall[actdataall['ORDValue'].isin(orddata['ORDER_ID'].unique())]['User ID']
```

Both, `actdataall` and `orddata` are Spark dataframes.

I don't want to use `toPandas()` function given the drawback associated with it.

Answer (score 5):

- If both dataframes are big, you should consider using an inner join which will work as a filter:

  First let's create a dataframe containing the order IDs we want to keep:

  ```py
  orderid_df = orddata.select(orddata.ORDER_ID.alias("ORDValue")).distinct()
  ```

  Now let's join it with our actdataall dataframe:

  ```py
  usersofinterest = actdataall.join(orderid_df, "ORDValue", "inner").select('User ID').distinct()
  ```
- If your target list of order IDs is small then you can use the pyspark.sql isin function as mentioned in furianpandit's post, don't forget to broadcast your variable before using it (spark will copy the object to every node making their tasks a lot faster):

  ```py
  orderid_list = orddata.select('ORDER_ID').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()[0]
  sc.broadcast(orderid_list)
  ```

Answer (score 4):

The most direct translation of your code would be:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# collect all the unique ORDER_IDs to the driver
order_ids = [x.ORDER_ID for x in orddata.select('ORDER_ID').distinct().collect()]

# filter ORDValue column by list of order_ids, then select only User ID column
usersofinterest = actdataall.filter(F.col('ORDValue').isin(order_ids)).select('User ID')
```

However, you should only filter like this only if number of 'ORDER_ID' is definitely small (perhaps <100,000 or so).

If the number of 'ORDER_ID's is large, you should use a broadcast variable which sends the list of order_ids to each executor so it can compare against the order_ids locally for faster processing.  Note, this will work even if 'ORDER_ID' is small.

```
order_ids = [x.ORDER_ID for x in orddata.select('ORDER_ID').distinct().collect()]
order_ids_broadcast = sc.broadcast(order_ids)  # send to broadcast variable
usersofinterest = actdataall.filter(F.col('ORDValue').isin(order_ids_broadcast.value)).select('User ID')
```

For more information on broadcast variables, check out: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-broadcast.html

Answer (score 1):

So, you have two spark dataframe. One is actdataall and other is orddata, then use following command to get your desire result.

```
usersofinterest  = actdataall.where(actdataall['ORDValue'].isin(orddata.select('ORDER_ID').distinct().rdd.flatMap(lambda x:x).collect()[0])).select('User ID')
```