# Pyspark Cannot modify a column based on a condition when a column values are in other list

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Pyspark 3.0.1

I want to modify the value of a column is in a list.

```py
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- ID: decimal(4,0) (nullable = true)
 |-- Provider: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Principal: float (nullable = false)
 |-- PRINCIPALBALANCE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- STATUS: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Installment Rate: float (nullable = true)
 |-- Yearly Percentage: float (nullable = true)
 |-- Processing Fee Percentage: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Disb Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ZOHOID: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- UPFRONTPROCESSINGFEEBALANCE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- WITHHOLDINGTAXBALANCE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- UPFRONTPROCESSINGFEEPERCENTAGE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- UPFRONTPROCESSINGFEEWHTPERCENTAGE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- PROCESSINGFEEWHTPERCENTAGE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- PROCESSINGFEEVATPERCENTAGE: float (nullable = true)
 |-- BUSINESSSHORTCODE: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EXCTRACTIONDATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- fake Fee: double (nullable = false)
 |-- fake WHT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fake Fee_WHT: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Agency Fee CP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Agency VAT CP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Agency WHT CP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Agency Fee_VAT_WHT CP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- write_offs: integer (nullable = false)

df.head(1)

[Row(ID=Decimal('16'), Provider='fake', Principal=2000.01, PRINCIPALBALANCE=0.2, STATUS=4, Installment Rate=0.33333333, Yearly Percentage=600.0, Processing Fee Percentage=0.20, Disb Date=None, ZOHOID=3000, UPFRONTPROCESSINGFEEBALANCE=None, WITHHOLDINGTAXBALANCE=None, UPFRONTPROCESSINGFEEPERCENTAGE=None, UPFRONTPROCESSINGFEEWHTPERCENTAGE=None, PROCESSINGFEEWHTPERCENTAGE=None, PROCESSINGFEEVATPERCENTAGE=16.0, BUSINESSSHORTCODE='20005', EXCTRACTIONDATE=datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 25, 5, 7, 58, 6000), fake Fee=1770.7, fake WHT='312.48', fake Fee_WHT='2,083.18', Agency Fee CP='566.62', Agency VAT CP='566.62', Agency WHT CP='186.39', Agency Fee_VAT_WHT CP='5,394.41')]
```

The value of the column of `'write_offs'` is 0 for all rows then I want to convert it to 1 if the column `ID` is in the following list: `list1 = [299, 570, 73, 401]`

Then I am doing:

```py
df.withColumn('write_offs', when((df.filter(df['ID'].isin(list1))),1).otherwise(df['ID']))
```

and I am getting this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-de9f9cd49ea5> in <module>
----> 1 df.withColumn('write_offs', when((df.filter(df['ID'].isin(userinput_write_offs_ids))),lit(1)).otherwise(df['ID']))

/usr/local/spark/python/pyspark/sql/functions.py in when(condition, value)
    789     sc = SparkContext._active_spark_context
    790     if not isinstance(condition, Column):
--> 791         raise TypeError("condition should be a Column")
    792     v = value._jc if isinstance(value, Column) else value
    793     jc = sc._jvm.functions.when(condition._jc, v)

TypeError: condition should be a Column
```

I don't know why is giving this error because I did a similar operation that the condition returns a dataframe and works.

I read how to use this isin function here:
[Pyspark isin function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44444632/pyspark-isin-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Boolean column for `when`, not a dataframe

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.withColumn(
    'write_offs',
    F.when(F.col('ID').isin(list1), 1)
     .otherwise(F.col('ID'))
)
```